# How to retain comment's position to be same, while re-order the other elements

Tags: xslt

Suggest for, How to retain comment's position to be same as in input file, while re-order the other elements which are same level siblings to comments. Here punctuation between elements are not required, only some elements are to be moved as given XSLT (version 2).

At present all comments are appearing at the end of all elements (apply-templates for comment() given at the end). Please suggest to get the required output as given below.

**XML:**

```
<article>
    <bm>
        <ref id="ref1">
            <au>Rudramuni TP</au>. (<year>2014</year>). <jtitle>Sun Family</jtitle>. <articleTitle>The Solar System</articleTitle>.<!--The comment related article--> <iss>2</iss>, <vol>11</vol>: <!--The comment related to volume --><fpage>1</fpage>-<lpage>12</lpage>
        </ref>
        <ref id="ref2">
            <au>Kishan TR</au>. (<year>2014</year>). <jtitle>Galxy</jtitle>. <articleTitle>The Galxy<!--The comment related to title --></articleTitle>. <iss>2</iss>, <vol>11</vol>: <fpage>1</fpage>-<!--The comment related to pages --><lpage>12</lpage>
        </ref>
    </bm>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ref">
        <xsl:element name="ref">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="au"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="articleTitle"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="jtitle"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="vol"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="iss"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="fpage"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="lpage"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="comment()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<article>
    <bm>
        <ref id="ref1"><au>Rudramuni TP</au>
            <articleTitle>The Solar System</articleTitle><!--The comment related article--><jtitle>Sun Family</jtitle>
            <year>2014</year><vol>11</vol><!--The comment related to volume --><iss>2</iss>
            <fpage>1</fpage><lpage>12</lpage>
        </ref>
        <ref id="ref2"><au>Kishan TR</au>
            <articleTitle>The Galxy<!--The comment related to title --></articleTitle><jtitle>Galxy</jtitle>
            <year>2014</year><vol>11</vol><iss>2</iss>
            <fpage>1</fpage><!--The comment related to pages --><lpage>12</lpage>
        </ref>
    </bm>
</article>
```

Comment: Is that really how your input looks, with periods and parentheses (which you do not want?) in between the nodes that you do want?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, input elements are having some delimiters, where as output side delimiters are not required, only tags are enough with position change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="comment" match="comment()" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref">
    <ref>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="au"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="articleTitle"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="jtitle"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="year"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="vol"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="iss"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fpage"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="lpage"/>
    </ref>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ref/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('comment', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sir, I assume that nothing is impossible related to XSLT, when u r get into action. U answered many of Questions with perfect code. Thanks a lot. Small clarification, are we can have control like this only on within 'ref' comments, bcs other other comments should not move within preceded elements.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the follow-up. See if the edited version above solves the problem.

Comment: U r suggestion is correct, working as required, I tested with altering the key code, with **match="ref//comment()"**